how to trim off edge of cabinet in place/make cabinet narrower
I want to replace a fridge but the new one is slightly too large for the existing floor cabinet gap (which should have been 36" but was 35.75" so new fridge barely won't make it).
I don't want to move the cabinet off the wall, if I can avoid that...more hassle.
Can I shave off 1/4" off the side of a cabinet?  If yes how, what tools, tricks?  It has a laminate countertop, don't want to nick that, desiring a straight final edge...
Lots of people describe how to trim a cabinet above a fridge, which usually has a lip hanging down you can trim off (and no top laminate surface to worry about), but this one is to the right...
This is what the cabinets currently like:

and this is what one looks like with the top off.

The current counter is "flush" with the side panel.  They did a poor job getting it flush though so it's kinda chipped, wouldn't mind getting it smooth and straight this time.
I also learned that there aren't screws holding this cabinet together, only I believe staples from the outside.
Thanks!

Had that problem with a fridge in a rental. I was able to remove the baseboard on the wall side and get the 1/2 inch I needed. maybe it could work for you.  Trying to cut a counter and have it look good is darn near impossible without removing the counter. Absolutely impossible to do a cabinet without removal.

It sounds like the cabinet side needs to be shorter than the counter top?  If so then you cut the inside supports, not the side.  Most cabinets on the floor are only held onto the wall by a couple of screws(if that).  Pictures will help.

When I redid my kitchen in 2000, I arranged things so that one side of the refrigerator was open, blocking part of the fixed half of a sliding door. Which meant that the next refrigerator could be wider with no consequences. But most kitchens aren't designed that way.

Is there space on the other side of the cabinet?  If so then floor cabinets should be easy to move over.

A picture that shows the edge of the countertop, and the side of the cabinet would be helpful.

Good ideas.  @Mark added some pics.

From what the pictures show, removing two screws if that many, will be a lot easier than cutting.  Might be missing something not shown.

You can remove the thin applied finish panel on the side, then trim down the overhang of the face frame, so it is flush with the structural cabinet side. I would start with a circular saw to do the rough cut removing most of the overhang, then possibly use a router with a flush cut bit to finish:

source
Sometimes these cabinets have metal pins or staples shot in from the inside of the cabinet into the frame. These pins may go far enough that they are in the part that needs to be trimmed off.
I would start with a circular saw and not the most expensive but reasonably sharp saw blade, then finish with a router for a final clean cut.
Make the cut from the face of the cabinet. Remove the door and hinge so the cabinet face is not bumpy. Lay a piece of plywood on the face of the cabinet, with the edge aligned to the structural side of the cabinet, so the saw and router have a wide face to run along.
Cut off most of the frame overhang with the saw. Leave about 1/16th inch (1mm) left. Use a straight edge clamped to the temporary face plywood so the saw runs straight.
After the saw cut, inspect the edge for pins or staples. If you don't see any, you could try moving the saw straightedge over another 1/32nd inch or half mmm and make another saw pass. If still no pins, either take a chance with the router, or if enough wood has been removed to get the fridge in and the saw cut was reasonably straight, skip the router and go to the paint.
If you must continue with the router, since the frame piece being trimmed is solid wood, you'll have to carefully climb-cut the router passes, so the wood does not splinter. Climb-cut gently, holding the router firmly and arms relatively stiffly so the router won't run away on you. Once the climb-cut passes have removed the overhang of the frame, make one final conventional-cut pass to finish the cut.
If removing the overhang allows the structural side to flop away or be loose from the frame, you could glue the frame to the side and shoot some pins, nails, or staples from the outside through the structural side into the frame. Finally sand, prime, & paint the cabinet side, and slide home the fridge.
With reasonable care these cuts can be done with the cabinet in place, as long as the countertop is off. But these operations would be safer and easier if the cabinet is laid down on its back.
Regarding the countertop, you could cut the top down from the bottom and back, so the saw teeth are cutting into the laminate from the face, which may reduce chipping. Use the plywood piece clamped in place so the saw has a face to slide on. You'll have to do two passes, one for the counter top and one for the backsplash. Then get a can of spray contact adhesive and a piece of laminate from a cabinet shop that reasonably matches the countertop laminate (fwiw basic white would be a fallback for me, since the side is being hidden by the fridge). Use the router and flush cut bit to trim back the glued-on laminate, then a file or sanding block to knock down the sharp edges and cut marks from the router bit.

I'll add that if this doesn't give enough room to slide in the refrigerator, you may be able to do the exact same thing to the other end of the cabinet, allowing the cabinet to be slid over just a bit.

Great advice. I didn't know such a router bit existed, and had forgotten about the side laminate entirely. Nice!  Maybe mark it underneath while still mounted then remove it and cut it.  Good idea.

Short of completely reconfiguring the existing cabinet, the most cost effective approach I can think of is to remove the cab, remove the drywall on the right, then re-attach the cab 1/2” over. If the wall with drywall is an exterior wall, this is a bad idea. This also won’t make your laminate edge nice, but since it’s mostly hidden by the fridge, this might fade from your sight.
Edit: my bad… I assumed the problem cab was in a corner, so this answer isn’t useful.

So basically sink it into the wall?  Interesting workaround option...I did have a related idea of moving it to the right a little and "smooshing" the space for the range that happens to be there...

This is still useful for those against a wall, or for me, equivalent was to scoot the cabinet right and scoot the oven to its right right as well (after trimming edges) in my case, and possibly the cabinet to the right of that... :)

I guess another equivalent would have been removing drywall from just left of the fridge.  Replace with narrower drywall or with a panel or with nothing.  Never thought of that, good one!

The climb cut is to make it easier to manage the router as it's used vertically, like with the weight of the thing?

@Triplefault would be the ultimate authority on his opinion, but the climb cut will tend to prevent splintering.

For some cabinets there is not a decorative end panel.  In my case there was, so I could remove that, and trim off the front side edge piece.  Planer almost worked but ran into staples when it got close to flush.  But kind of worked eventually and looked pretty good.
You can also check for things like molding sticking out of the edge of the cabinet bottom or trim on the walls and remove that.  Or check if the countertop extends over the edge of the cabinet, then you could trim just the countertop.  Go for potentially easier stuff than modifying the cabinet itself.
In terms of trimming the countertop in place, I tried a planer but it didn't work on the laminate edge perfectly.  Only worked well on the long middle section.  Chipped othe edges.  Oscillating tool up into the laminate from the bottom is hard to control and chipped edges (though marking the top and oscillating from above one guy seemed ok with).
Ended up sanding stuff down.  You can Google "cut counter to fit fridge" or "cut counter top flush with cabinet" for related ideas.  Jigsaw with japanese pull cut saw to finish off the backsplash is a suggestion.  Plus sand it.  NB jigsaw with no "edge to keep it straight" will wander easily.
You might get lucky and be able to leave the counter backsplash there and not cut it, if it's for a fridge that won't end up flush with the back wall anyway (tip from a YouTube).
I ended up trimming off the cabinet edge plus its opposite edge to the right, plus the edge of the cabinet past the oven to the right of that, then moving the the oven and then cabinet to the right (oven still needed a 36" gap).  I removed the decorative end panels as well.   The combination gave me enough space.
There is another style of cabinet that has a thin "side wall" over a frame (and no decorative end panel and lip for easy removal).  If this is your cabinet, an option might be to remove a whole wall and leave it off, if the open wall isn't visible because it's flush with an appliance. Assuming your cabinet has beams inside that for structural integrity.  Another option for that style cabinet might be to remove the wall, then plane down the side of the frame slightly, then replace it.  Or google "how to shorten cabinet" if you're willing to pull it out and do more drastic measures on it before putting it back in smaller...or have another style of cabinet that's just thick walls.
To unscrew a cabinet to pull out from the wall you can do it without removing the top, start backing the two back screws out with Hammer drill, then manual screwdriver if the angles stop letting the hammer drill bit grip.  And address the caulk at the top and sides.  Moving cabinets sometimes you have to move flooring as well.
If you're really desperate for door open clearance you may be able to trim off the corner front lip of counter that's nearest the fridge then angle the fridge in that direction.  Or cut out/replace with smaller drywall where a fridge door protrusion swings into a wall (ref)
You may be able to adjust the "feet" under the front of a fridge to make it sit up straighter or even lean toward a particular wall, if useful.
Things that didn't work: oscillating tool with small wood blade coming from the back at an angle: for the front edge piece it chips it and wanders, for laminate cover coming from the bottom it chips it and wanders.  Some other combination (half moon bit? Angle?) might be ok.
I have not had great luck with a belt sander and low grit sandpaper on cabinets, kinda hard to control.  Maybe for the rough beginnings.  Planer is easier to control.  palm-head orbital sander seemed to work pretty well, though slower, easier to control.  I also wonder (some things don't work cuz they have nails in them) if maybe a reciprocating saw could cut through for a first pass cut...since there are reciprocating blades that can cut through metal.  Might need/want a guide for it.  Or a metal jigsaw blade.  More teeth the better for a finer cut...
It worked and I have the 36" now, and the fridge inserts as easy as expected now.

That's all I know so far...
